# Track fingers in UIViewController

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, touchesbegan

I want to track down the position of my fingers in a UIViewController. I implemented this with the following function and this is working great!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  //Create subview and place it under your finger.
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  //Here methods which tracks the moves of the finger and updates the subviews position.
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  //Remove subview from superview overhere.
}
```

I have two issues:

1. When I press more than 5 fingers on the screen, touchesBegin/touchesMoved/touchesEnded will not be called anymore. Even when I place 6 fingers and remove 1.
2. Sometimes touchesBegan is called from random positions on my screen. TouchesEnded is called for the same point after that.

Should I implement this on another way? I also tried it using UIGestureRecognizer but without success.

I added this function

```
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
}
```

And this is called when I tap the 6th finger on the screen.

Comment: What device are you using? iPhones can only make use of 5 fingers while I found that iPads register 11...

Comment: I use an iPhone which indeed can register only 5 fingers. But does this mean that the touch actions ends when the 6th finger is pressed?

Comment: Good question. Maybe it gets irritated :D